# How to remap keyboard function keys to be reached directly?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

Today most keyboards have function keys (<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, …, <kbd>F1</kbd>) are mapped on the keys to be reached with the simultaneous fn/kbd> key.

As a developer, I use much more frequently function keys than other functions mapped (luminosity +/-, volume +/-, ...), so I ask:

On Linux, how to remap function keys to be directly reachable, without any modifier, and possibly remap other functions mapped to be reached via the `fn` modifier?

Comment: Maybe [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey) might help you? Its Windows alternative, [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) does a great job in fixing keyboard's weirdness.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you (usually) can't. The `fn` key mappings are managed by hardware. Some laptops (such as the Thinkpad) allow you to edit that functionality in the BIOS so that the default behaviour (without pressing `fn`) is the F1..F12 keys.

Edit: Looks like there may be ways to address this on certain keyboards using Solaar. See the following answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/285512/how-to-change-function-fn-key-behavior-on-wireless-logitech-keyboard

Comment: Would one be able to bypass using the `fn` keys with an external keyboard?

Comment: In the laptop case, sure. The `fn` key is not a normal modifier like `shift` or `ctrl`. It causes the keyboard itself to send modified scancodes, and as such the behaviour is entirely dependent on the keyboard itself (and in the case of some laptops, a BIOS-controlled keyboard configuration).

Comment: Thanks for the link! I am interested with the builtin keyboard... I didn't know about BIOS setting on the Thinkpad...

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Apple keyboard, try [these instructions for Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apple_Keyboard#Function_keys_do_not_work) or [these instructions for Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard#Change_Function_Key_behavior):

1. In a terminal, run `echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode`
2. If the function keys start working, make it permanent by creating `/etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf` with these contents:

   ```
   options hid_apple fnmode=2
   ```
3. Then regenerate your initial ramdisk. In Arch Linux, run `sudo mkinitcpio -p linux`. In Ubuntu, run `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`. Other distros should have documentation on this.

It's worth trying even if you don't have an Apple keyboard because some keyboards report as Apple keyboards. (For example, my Varmilo keyboard shows up as an Apple keyboard.)